# What is a RAID Controller's Sideband Cable used for?

Tags: raid, sas, cable

I have some Adaptec SAS raid controllers and the fanout cable comes with an extra cable called a SideBand but I am curious what it does?

I know it plugs into the backplane, but other than that I can't seem to find anything on google

The adaptec site refers to it as "SFF-8448 sideband signals" and there is no mention of it in the manuals or their site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sideband cables are used to connect the controller to a managed backplane or disk enclosure, so that it can monitor the controller as well as the disks.

Comment: That's kind of obvious, I have figured that out. But what specifically does it do? Thanks.

Comment: It lets the backplane monitor the status of the Raid controller and send alerts should there be a problem. What else do you want to know
? The specifics of how it talks to the controller?

Answer (score 12):

This [PDF document](ftp://ftp.seagate.com/pub/sff/SFF-8448.PDF) *"SFF-8448 Specification for SAS Sideband Signal Assignments"*, (Rev. 05; September 2, 2005) on Seagate's FTP Server defines the signal assignments for known Vendor specific sidebands thata are defined in SAS (Serial Attached SCSI).

On page 12 there is a description of the Sideband Assignments.